# Unable to read hindi font on Windows Server 2003

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, activereports

I have a `WinForm` application where I am using `Active Reports` to display reports. I have implemented globalization for English and Hindi font.
I use two operating systems: `Windows 7` and `Windows Server 2003`. In Windows 7 it is reading hindi font but in Windows server 2003 it shows squares instead of hindi font characters. I have no idea where the problem is?

Comment: Perhaps the fonts are not installed on the 2003 box?

Comment: so were you able to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

you should check to be sure the font is installed. if not installed then you can take a copy of the font file from one of the other PC's and send it over.

if it is not compatible with the 2003 pc for some reason you can likely find it to download and install on the server.

Here is a [How To Install Fonts](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314960) and [here is an article](http://redwerb.com/post/Embedding-Fonts-in-your-Net-Application.aspx) that shows you how to embed the font as a resource in the Winform project, this way in the future you do not have to worry if the font is installed or not.

hope this helps